# How to know user clicked "Not Allow" button when iOS ask user to grant permission to access camera or Library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, uiimagepickercontroller

On iOS8+, user first time to access the Camera or Library. in this moment system will show a alertView to let user to grant the permission, **so i want to know is there have any way to know user have click "Not allow"?**

Appreciate your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464631/detect-permission-of-camera-in-ios?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742578/objective-c-how-to-detect-user-has-clicked-dont-allow-access-to-photos-button

Comment: Click on this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742578/objective-c-how-to-detect-user-has-clicked-dont-allow-access-to-photos-button

Comment: @surendarreddy Thanks

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Thanks